# How do I configure my Netbeans IDE to run my Ruby on Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, configuration, ruby-on-rails-5, netbeans-platform

I'm using Apache Netbeans 11.1 for Mac OS X.  I just opened a Ruby on Rails 5 project.  I want to run my server from the IDE, so I went to the "Run" menu and selected "Run Project (my_project)".  However, what I see next is

[image]

The "Start File" and "Web Server" options don't seem to have anything to do with a Ruby on Rails environment, nor do the options on the left.  What else do I need to do to configure my IDE to recognize my project as a valid RoR 5 project?

Comment: RoR development is definitely not supported "out of the box" in NetBeans 11.x, and as far as I know there is also no RoR plugin available for NetBeans versions > 8.x. Can you provide a link to any relevant documentation if that is not the case?

Comment: If it's not supported, that's all I needed to know.

Comment: OK. I kept looking and I'm pretty sure that for any NetBeans version > 8.x you won't be able to do RoR development in NetBeans unfortunately.